# How did i go? Find the exact value of ... $\frac{z^{43}}{w^{87}}-\frac{\bar{z}^{23}}{w^{41}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

---

$$\frac{z^{43}}{w^{87}}-\frac{\bar{z}^{23}}{w^{41}}$$

$ z=1-\sqrt{3}i = 2e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}i} \\ \bar{z} = 1+\sqrt{3}i = 2e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i} \\ w = 1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}$

Then by de moivre's theorem and basic trigonometry

$ z^{43} = 2^{43}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right) \\ w^{87} = 2^{\frac{87}{2}}\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}i\right) \\ \bar{z^{43}} = 2^{23}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right) \\ w^{41} = 2^{\frac{41}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right)$

Then.. By another tedious process of multiplying by a conjugate factor of one then cancelling powers I got.....

$$\frac{z^{43}}{w^{87}}-\frac{\bar{z}^{23}}{w^{41}}=\frac{1}{2} \left( (-7+9\sqrt{3})+ (9+7\sqrt{3})i \right)$$

I'm worried as there is a hint I didn't use...
"HINT: it may help to know that $\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4} $ and $\frac{7\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}$"

Haha, does anyone know how (or if) I can input this into wolfram alpha? I know I remember there's a way to make it like "a+b .... where {a=2+x,b=2-x}"

Comment: I suppose you lost a $2$ somewhere $$\frac{z^{43}}{w^{87}}-\frac{\bar{z}^{23}}{w^{41}}=\frac{1}{4} \left( (-7+9\sqrt{3})+ (9+7\sqrt{3})i \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to keep using polar representation and avoid tedious calculations. This way we have:
$$
\frac{z^{43}}{w^{87}} = \frac{2^{43}e^{\frac{215\pi i}{3}}}{\sqrt{2}^{87}e^{\frac{87\pi i}{4}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{\frac{599\pi i}{12}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{-\frac{\pi i}{12}} = \frac{1+\sqrt3}{4}+i\frac{1-\sqrt3}{4}
$$